# Passing Env variables from the server to your Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, dockerfile

I have referred the following document where I have to set variable from the docker.

https://medium.com/@vietgoeswest/passing-env-variables-from-the-server-to-your-create-react-app-c87578a45358"

But I am facing the following issue while setting the environment

```
sh: window.RUNTIME_API_HOST=’https://abcd.com’: not found
```

What Do I need to set for setting RUNTIME_API_HOST. I have tried so many time but no successful.

Comment: Can you include the code that causes this error in the question?  Also, can you double-check that your quotes are "plain" `'` single quotes?

Comment: @DavidMaze, single quotes is there and following is the script #!/bin/bash
 if [ ! -z ${API_HOST} ]; then
 cat <<END
 window.RUNTIME_API_HOST=’${API_HOST}’;
END
fi

Comment: Please include that in the question; the formatting can be important.  (Your error implies the heredoc is getting executed, which doesn't seem right.)